# Screenshot desktop while a Windows Store app is active?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, screenshot, windows-8.1, desktop

In Windows 8.1, the desktop still exists when a Windows Store (Modern/Metro) tiled app is active, correct? (I'm assuming this because of the speed of manually switching back and forth.) If so, is there a way to programatically capture a "screenshot" of the desktop when it is in the background? Failing that, a is there a way to force the desktop to the front before the screen is captured via System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen()?

FYI, my application is an internet monitoring service that I think the user is trying to circumvent by leaving the Store Solitaire app up while other activities are going on on the (hiden, but active) desktop.

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5485101/2589202

Comment: I think there's a difference between creating multiple desktops and what I'm asking, though of course without knowing the answer I can't be sure.